# How to store Effect parameters in class ?

Tags: c#, xna, shader, effect

How to store `Effect` parameters in class ?
I'm stuck in this problem for the 3rd day now and I think I'm slowly going to be insane.

I tried to create a class named `EffectParameter` so I can store/set my parameter values for each object's shader dynamically.

I tried the to store the `ParameterValue` in Object type

```
Object ParameterData;
```

But I encountered a problem where I need to read from this class....this is where everything going down in the hill.

The method `effect.Parameters["parametername"].SetValue()`  only accept a few kind of types.
And I cannot pass an object to this method.

So I tried to Cast this object.

```
public T ReadData<T>()
{
    return (T)(object)this.ParameterDataVal;
}
```

But with this my problem is that I need to know the specific type of this object when I set it (`Float`,`Texture2D` etc.)

And I cannot use a type variable to determine the type of this object.
I tried to use `(typevariable)(object)this.ParameterDataVal;`
But it just gave me errors.

I was mad,so I searched the net for solution for dynamic typing.
But I found no method for my problem.

Then I realized maybe I'm making problems of a simple thing.
So I decided to I use an `EffectParameter` to store my data.

But then I had another problem with this, again when I try to set this data to the effect....
So I tried to give this Parameter to the effect with a method,but I still getting error that 'It's readonly.'.

So I cannot add my `EffectParameter` to the collection.
I tried many ways. But no success.

I'm totally lost in this. I have no idea what else to do.

Anybody ever encountered this problem or somebody can provide me a good solution plan?

Comment: I think your class layout is unclear. Are you using a class `Effect`, with a property `Parameters` of some dictionary type? And is `SetValue` a method of that dictionary? More code would help.

Comment: I tried to use in the 2nd solution that I store an EffectParameter object,so in the constructor it's just a new EffectParamter with SetValue. So I have my EffectParameter with the value already.
But when I want to call a method to set this effectparameter to the effect, I get only errors about that effect.Parameters is read only,and I cannot add my effect parameter from my class. And I have no idea about the solution.

Comment: I can't quite follow you. Please post your definition of `Effect` and other relevant code.

Comment: I provided all things to understand my problem..

Comment: @phg - Effect and EffectParameter are both defined via XNA, so he wouldn't be able to change those. As for the OP, I'm not sure why you feel it is necessary to do this at all. If each object needs to set effect parameters separately, why not just make a method in your object class which accepts an Effect as a parameter (they are references, correct? not structs?), and modifies its variables as needed by the object? Then just call that method before drawing an object.

Comment: Yes but with that solution i had many problems right now :D
But it solves this question! So i'm thankful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution's class:

```
    public class ObjectShader
    {

        public Effect effect;

        public System.Drawing.Image TextureImage;

        public string ShaderName;

        string TechniqueName;


            public ObjectShader(string name,Effect ef)
            {
                this.ShaderName = name;
                this.effect = ef;


            }


            public void SetValue(string name, System.Drawing.Image val)
            {
                this.TextureImage = val;

            }



            public void SetValue(string name,float val)
            {
                this.effect.Parameters[name].SetValue(val);

            }

            public void SetValue(string name, float[] val)
            {
                this.effect.Parameters[name].SetValue(val);

            }


            public void SetValue(string name, string val)
            {
                this.effect.Parameters[name].SetValue(val);

            }

            public void SetValue(string name, Matrix val)
            {
                this.effect.Parameters[name].SetValue(val);

            }

            public void SetValue(string name, Matrix[] val)
            {
                this.effect.Parameters[name].SetValue(val);

            }

            public void SetValue(string name, Vector2 val)
            {
                this.effect.Parameters[name].SetValue(val);

            }

            public void SetValue(string name, Vector2[] val)
            {
                this.effect.Parameters[name].SetValue(val);

            }

            public void SetValue(string name, Vector3 val)
            {
                this.effect.Parameters[name].SetValue(val);

            }

            public void SetValue(string name, Vector3[] val)
            {
                this.effect.Parameters[name].SetValue(val);

            }

            public void SetValue(string name, int val)
            {
                this.effect.Parameters[name].SetValue(val);

            }
            public void SetValue(string name, int[] val)
            {
                this.effect.Parameters[name].SetValue(val);

            }


    }
}
```